# Start and exit actions in while loops

Tags: design-patterns, loops

Sometimes I find it useful to have loops that do an action at the beginning and/or the end of a `while` loop.

The best way I can think of for representing this in C++ would be:

```
if(condition) {
    // Pre-loop actions.
    while(condition) {
        // Loop actions
    }
    // Post-loop actions.
}
```

Or with a `goto` optimization (theoretically):

```
if(condition) {
    // Pre-loop actions.
    goto loopStart;
    while(condition) {
            loopStart:
        // Loop actions
    }
    // Post-loop actions.
}
```

Do any programming languages had a more formal structure to represent this? Is this the best structural construction in C-like languages (e.g. has this been discussed in computer science literature)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understand what sorts of things you are thinking of here. A more concrete realistic example might help.

But I personally find the example you gave in C++ already quite reasonable.

Please note also - there is a 'for loop' in C++, which comes very close to doing what you are describing.

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for)

```
for ( init-statement; condition(optional) ; iteration_expression(optional) ) statement
```

So you can write:

```
for (Pre-loop actions; condition; Post-loop actions) {
    // Loop actions
}
```

But here the pre-loop actions get done even if condition is false.
And post-loop-actions get done every time through the loop.

There is another pattern I find VERY helpful, that you may be thinking of, and thats a 'finally' block. That nicely handles the cleanup after look logic.

For example see [example use of Finally](https://github.com/SophistSolutions/Stroika/blob/bdde398fd56da7c107e21612b8a68d32c92a49fd/Library/Sources/Stroika/Foundation/Configuration/SystemConfiguration.cpp#L238)

```
        [[maybe_unused]] auto&& cleanup = Execution::Finally ([]() noexcept { ::endutxent (); });
        ::setutxent ();
        for (const utmpx* i = ::getutxent (); i != nullptr; i = ::getutxent ()) {
            if (i->ut_type == BOOT_TIME) {
                result.fBootedAt = DateTime (i->ut_tv);
                succeeded        = true;
            }
        }
```

here the 'finally' block is declared before the loop, but done afterwards (as going out of scope) - so useful for cleanup activities (especially in the presense of exceptions).

Answer (score 1):

Since you already know the condition of the `while` loop is true when the loop is first encountered, you can change it to be a `do`/`while` loop:

```
if(condition) {
    // Pre-loop actions.
    do {
        // Loop actions
    } while(condition);
    // Post-loop actions.
}
```

That way the condition isn't checked again until after the loop has run once.

Answer (score 0):

To write loops (other than those that iterate for a specific count), I use a third option, preferring the use of infinite loop with `break;` from somewhere in the loop:

```
// Pre-loop actions
for (;;) {
    // Pre-condition actions (e.g. prompt or prime)
    if ( ! condition ) 
        break;
    // post-condition actions (e.g. the main loop-body actions)
}
// Post-loop actions
```

This is about as DRY as you'll get.  Using a `while` often requires that the prompt/priming code is duplicated, e.g. once outside the loop and once in the loop.

Also, this approach doesn't duplicate testing of the condition.  I can imagine in some cases the whole loop needs to be done conditionally as you're suggesting; however, I would submit that the pre- and post-loop actions ideally would work ok even if the loop doesn't run any actual iterations; the less conditional logic, the better.

Comment: I can see this as being useful as long as the pre-loop actions and post-loop actions aren't absolutely dependent on the condition and are relatively inexpensive. The other argument besides (premature?) optimization for using a conditional followed closely by one-time loop initialization actions is it makes the pre-loop actions more explicitly part of the loop. But you correctly point out that `condition` is repeated, which may be problematic if `condition` is non-trivial. Of course if condition *is* nontrivial, one could make it into a lambda.

Comment: But also notable is that this approach can be done in lieu of gotos, even with the conditional wrapped around it. This sort of takes a variant `do-while` approach, which is a useful reminder.